# What does a run represent on openml?

Tags: machine-learning

This [openml link](https://www.openml.org/t/3573) seems to be a benchmark for mnist.

There are 13133 runs in there.

[image]

What does a run represent? If I submit 2 versions, say vgg16 and svm. Do they count for another 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A run represents the result of a flow on a specific task.
So yes it would be two